# It's there a upnp player support playing the m3u playlist from DMS?

Tags: playback, upnp, dlna, m3u

It's there a upnp player support playing the m3u playlist from DMS? Not playing next and next manualy from the DLNA control point.

I'm going to write a DMR could parse m3u playlist but the upnp or DLNA document says so little about it.

Comment: It's that a OpenHome Media Renderer if implemented this?